# Finding and displaying Contours opencv python. Errors

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am having trouble finding and displaying Contours in opencv.

```
if first_frame == False:
            motion_frame = cv2.absdiff(croped_frame, compare_frame)
            cv2.imshow("motion frame", motion_frame)
            threshhold = cv2.threshold(motion_frame, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
            cv2.imshow("threshhold", threshhold)

            contour_frame = croped_frame.copy
            contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshhold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
            cv2.drawContours(contour_frame, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
            cv2.imshow("contour_frame", contour_frame)
```

```
cv2.drawContours(contour_frame, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

From all the research I have done this line of code that is giving me the error seems to be correct. As far as I can see there is no missing argument.

I would appreciate if someone could point out what has gone wrong and why and how to fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=typeError+Expected+Ptr+UMat+for+argument

Comment: `contour_frame = croped_frame.copy` -- you forgot to invoke the `copy`, so you're trying to draw contours into a function object. Next time, start your research by inspecting the actual value of all the variables you pass to the function.

Comment: of course. its always those silly mistakes. thanks.